# Parallelizing a data dependence loop with OpenMP

Tags: parallel-processing, dependencies, openmp

I have to parallelize the following code, the data dependence is i -> i-3

```
 for(i=3; i<N2; i++)
        for(j=0; j<N3; j++)
        {
          D[i][j] = D[i-3][j] / 3.0 + x + E[i];
          if (D[i][j] < 6.5) bat = bat + D[i][j]/100.0;
       }
```

I tried with `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:bat) private(i,j) shared(D,x,E)` and similar things but it wasn't correct

Comment: You already posted this question and then deleted it just as I was giving an answer.  Do you plan to leave the question this time?  You have a race condition in D[i][j].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider two threads and why parallelizing the outer loop is failing.

```
Thread 1: i=3, j=0.  This reads D[0][0] and writes D[3][0]
Thread 2: i=6, j=0.  This reads D[3][0] and writes D[6][0]
```

So thread 2 reads `D[3][0]`, the same value that thread 1 is writing.  That's the race condition.  I think if you parallelize the inner loop you won't have a problem.

```
for(i=3; i<N2; i++) {
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:bat) private(j)        
    for(j=0; j<N3; j++) {
        D[i][j] = D[i-3][j] / 3.0 + x + E[i];
        if (D[i][j] < 6.5) bat = bat + D[i][j]/100.0;
    }
}
```

Edit: I forgot to add the reduction and make j private.  I fixed that now.

Comment: I realized after the fact the main problem is probably not the race condition, though that is a problem, but that you have three independent dependency changes (D[3k][j] -> D[3k+3][j], D[3k+1][j] -> D[3k+4][j], and D[3k+2][j] -> D[3k+5][j]).  You might be able to exploit that fact to increase the parallelism further.

Comment: parallelizing by columns? the speedup is 2 with 32 cores, the acceleration factor isn't very good...